# VBA Merge Cells with loop through Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a WS looking like this [image]

I have This code :

```
Dim w As Long

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sht = wb.ActiveSheet

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For w = 1 To lCol

   Range(.Cells(1, w), .Cells(2, w), .Cells(3, w)).Merge

Next w
```

I want to make the cells Merged and Centered like this : [image]

But I cannot find the right way to make it. I want to Merge the first 3 cells in every column 
Example : A1:A3, but there are too many columns so i want to loop through them .
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! This is the answer

```
  For w = 1 To lCol

     With sht
         Range(Cells(1, w), Cells(3, w)).Merge

     End With

  Next w
```

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(1, w), .Cells(3, 2)).Merge`. Periods are important :-)

Comment: No need to use a `With` statement - you use the `Rows` and `Columns` properties instead: `sht.Rows("1:3").Columns(w).Merge`